# Remote linked servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a SQL Server 2008R2, and I want to connect remotely to a SQL Server 2012SP1, for which I am given:

```
IP: 12.34.56.78
Login: john
Password: pw1
Database: TESTDB
Table: test_table
```

The remote database is outside my LAN, but firewall is configured on both sides, so I can query it by opening SSMS directly from my database server.
I perform the following:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver '12.34.56.78', 'SQL Server';
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = [12.34.56.78], @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = 'john', @rmtpassword = 'pw1'
```

Up to now, no error, and I can see the linked server in SSMS, "Test Connection" is successful but I cannot query it.

```
select * from [12.34.56.78].TESTDB.test_table
```

Returns this error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name '12.34.56.78.TESTDB.test_table'.
```

What is the proper way to define a linked server from the Internet, and if possible assigning a nice name to it (rather than referring to it by IP)?
Should I be using SQLNCLI as a provider?

Comment: you are missing the schema name in your query. It should be [LINKED_SERVER].[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[OBJECT_NAME]. So in your case, [12.34.56.78].TESTDB.[HERE SHOULD BE YOUR MISSING SCHEMA].test_table

Comment: Hey, it works, thanks! (stupid me)
But how can I refer to the server with a better name, rather than the IP address?

Comment: It's a public IP address. Hopefully is a firewall's address that routes the traffic to a SQL Server! If it has a DNS name assigned to it, then you could use it. Or you could create a [SYNONYM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) and forget about typing this long name.

Comment: That's all I wanted to know. Please make this an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the schema name in your query. It should be [LINKED_SERVER].[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[OBJECT_NAME]. So in your case, [12.34.56.78].TESTDB.[HERE SHOULD BE YOUR MISSING SCHEMA].test_table

It's a public IP address. Hopefully it is a firewall's address that routes the traffic to a SQL Server! If it has a DNS name assigned to it, then you could use it. Or you could create a [SYNONYM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) and forget about typing this long name.

```
CREATE SYNONYM [schema].[synonym_name] FOR [LINKED_SERVER].[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[OBJECT_NAME]
```

Comment: I can now query the remote database:

select * from [12.34.56.78].TESTDB.dbo.test_table

It seems SYNONYM does not work as I expected.
I tried with:

> CREATE SYNONYM REMOTESERVER [12.34.56.78]

> select * from REMOTESERVER.TESTDB.dbo.test_table

Error is:

Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server 'REMOTESERVER' in sys.servers

Even better, I would like to do something like:

> CREATE SYNONYM REMOTEDB [12.34.56.78].TESTDB